# How to specify mobile devices web-app to be tested for in the Requirements?

Tags: test-management, test-design, requirements-validation, compatibility-testing

It's easy to specify the requirements for web-applications used on laptops (max-min screen width, set of browsers, set of OS) e.g.:

- screen from 1280 x 802 to 1600 x 992px liquid layout, and static for bigger screens
- browsers IE9-11; Chrome, Firefox, Opera, Safari (last version)
- OS Windows, Mac OS

There are billions of mobile devices which can handle web-applications. So how would you specify the range application is developed for? And testing strategy to cover this range?

The criteria I've found so far:

- operating system: Android / iOS
- landscape and portrait layout
- width from X1 to X2 px adaptive layout
- *should I specify devices directly Samsung XXX, BlackBerry XXX, iPhone X...?*

Comment: Is your web-application sensitive to the specific device being used? If so, you may need to list them all specifically. If not, there is no need to do so.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere, could you please tell me when these cases (web-application sensitive to the specific device) will happen? Have you ever come across them?

Comment: Yes. My company built a web application that responded with a different UI when it detected that it was being viewed on a mobile device. But the detection only cared about desktop-vs-mobile. It never cared about *which* mobile device was being used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen this kind of specifications in companies where their users are provided with specific devices, as for example, doctors inside a hospital to access to the patients clinical registers... because they know that the app (or web) will be used only for a reduced set of devices.

Another example, is when you are focusing on a specific market (China, US, etc.). Then, you'll probably know which are the most typical devices, but it's so dynamic (after one year there will be different set of most-used devices).
As I see it, it doesn't make sense to specify this. It's probably better to let this job to the test team, adjusting the set of devices on each release... according to the current most-used set.

Hope it helps!
Regards

Comment: As for me, it was enogh to specify OS (with mobile browser): Android (Chrome, Opera), iOS (Safari), Windows Phone (IE) and screen resolution.